# Добавление иззображения на кнопку через тег input

Tags: html, изображения, form, input, button

Привет, форумчане. Хочу сделать кнопку с текстом и рисунком на ней. Знаю, что это можно сделать через тег button, где внутри тега просто ставишь тег img с путём к картинке. Но мне нужно при нажатии на кнопку отправлять данные на сервер, соответственно, для этого нужен тег input. Так вот, как сделать кнопку с картинкой в теге input? Прочитал, что можно использовать атрибут src с указанием пути к картинке, но картинка в кнопке не отображается. Код тега ниже.

```html
<form action="" method="get">
  <input type="submit" name="buy" value="В корзину" src="imgs/tiny/buy.jpeg">
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Но мне нужно при нажатии на кнопку отправлять данные на сервер, соответственно, для этого нужен тег input* - это Вы с чего взяли?

Просто присвойте button type="submit" и всё будет отправляться.

Comment: Как всё просто..спасибо, помогло. Не думал, что в баттоне можно такой атрибут использовать.

Comment: @SnoopDoggyDog, почитайте, вдруг пригодится на будущее: https://puzzleweb.ru/html/tag_button.php

Comment: спасибо, сохранил к себе

Answer (score 1):

Просто присвойте button type="submit" этот style.

```
<input type="submit" value="" style="background-image: url('images/img.png'); 
border:none; background-repeat:no-repeat;background-size:100% 100%;">
```